# jquery fullcalendar event with JSON web method

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I want to use jquery full calendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in my .net project.
Please refer code -

ASPX file-

```
var req = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scheduleTest.aspx/getAllScheduledSessionsOfLocation",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $(OnSuccess(data.d))
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, text, error) { debugger; alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText); },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });

        function OnSuccess(dataTable) {
            if (dataTable.length == 0) {
                $('#calendar').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    editable: true,
                    events: dataTable,
                    eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                        alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                            '(should probably update your database)');
                    },
                    loading: function(bool) {
                        if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                        else $('#loading').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

WebMethod : scheduleTest.aspx/getAllScheduledSessionsOfLocation
This webMethod returns formated string.

IMP : scheduleTest.aspx/getAllScheduledSessionsOfLocation() is returning foll string-

```
"[{ title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', allDay: false, start: '02/20/2012 1:30:00 PM', end: '02/20/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', allDay: false, start: '02/27/2012 1:30:00 PM', end: '02/27/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'abc xyz', allDay: false, start: '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM', end: '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM', end: '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'rtew ', allDay: false, start: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM', end: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM'}]"
```

NOTE : If I copy and paste a string which has been returned by above webmethod in Event of fullcalender, it is showing the output correctly.
But when I assign returned object to event (like - events: dataTable) then it is not showing events.

Problem : I think I got the issue. 
If I pass foll. code in event - then it is working

```
events: [{ title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', allDay: false, start: '02/20/2012 1:30:00 PM', end: '02/20/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', allDay: false, start: '02/27/2012 1:30:00 PM', end: '02/27/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'abc xyz', allDay: false, start: '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM', end: '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM', end: '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'rtew ', allDay: false, start: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM', end: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM'}],
```

But when I added double quote arround returned string then it isnt showing events. Like-

```
events: "[{ title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', allDay: false, start: '02/20/2012 1:30:00 PM', end: '02/20/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', allDay: false, start: '02/27/2012 1:30:00 PM', end: '02/27/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'abc xyz', allDay: false, start: '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM', end: '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM', end: '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM' }, { title: 'bhuvana ', allDay: false, start: '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM', end: '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { title: 'rtew ', allDay: false, start: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM', end: '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM'}]",
```

When I debug JSON method code using firebug, "data.d" contains a string with double quote. I think thats the problem.

Comment: provide sample of data including the very beginning..is there an array "d"?

Comment: @charlietfl : data.d contains a string.. I edited above post. please see for more details.

Comment: save everything you get in browser console from response and put it in a pastebin or jsfiddle.net  ....string doesn't sound right and I don't understand what you mean by "copy and paste"..where?

Comment: @charlietfl : sorry. please see now. Just now I edited.

Comment: ok ..there is no "d" in `$(OnSuccess(data.d))`...and should not be a quotes wrapping the whole array....should be json. Paste what you have in jsonlint.com

Comment: JSON must be double quoted also..your data is just not valid

Answer (score 0):

OK, Abhi... looking at the output and comparing it to my json feed I have quotes around every keyword and value so my output using your data would look like this:

```
[{ 'title': 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf', 'start': '02/20/2012 1:30:00 PM', 'end': '02/20/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { 'title': 'Puneet sdfsdfsdf','start': '02/27/2012 1:30:00 PM', 'end': '02/27/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { 'title': 'bhuvana ', 'start': '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM', 'end': '03/05/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { 'title': 'bhuvana ', 'start': '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM', 'end': '07/09/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { 'title': 'abc xyz', 'start': '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM', 'end': '07/09/2012 6:00:00 AM' }, { 'title': 'bhuvana ', 'start': '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM', 'end': '07/11/2012 7:30:00 PM' }, { 'title': 'bhuvana ', 'start': '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM', 'end': '07/16/2012 2:00:00 PM' }, { 'title': 'rtew ', 'start': '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM', 'end': '08/25/2014 6:00:00 AM'}]
```

As all your events have start and end dates I would use the allDayDefault:false param.
Try this and if you still have problems try changing the time format as I had issues with the format I used until I formatted my time to this format:

```
'2012-02-27T14:00:00+0000'
```

Hope this helps.